# Windows - Release & Renew IP in one step?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Is a batch file the only way to release and renew an IP in one step?

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

I unfortunately have to admin some Windows servers using Remote Desktop. Obviously if I type `ipconfig /release`, then I'll loose my connection and won't be able to `ipconfig /renew`. Obviously this can be done with .bat files, but I wanted to ask the pros just to see if there were any other tricks to doing it in the Windows server world.

Comment: The 'pros' would look to have an out-of-band remote management solution such as HP Integrated Lights Out or Dell's DRAC system in place. It then doesn't matter if the main network interfaces are functional with a correct IP address or not, you can still remote control the server to get them changed and working again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most people I think just either use static IP addresses for servers, or fixed DHCP assignments, and don't change IP addresses outside of scheduled reboots (Changing endpoints on running servers=bad). A bat file seems the simplest solution, but honestly even a straight up release should autorenew an IP address before the remote desktop session times out.

Comment: in agreement, sounds odd to have renew the ip address of a server- it is generally not recommended.

Comment: +1 DHCP on a server is not recommended at all, but I'd go with a right-click Repair on the NIC properties in the systray; that should work too and on a remote workstation I just tried, my RDP session persisted without issue.

Comment: I'm in the process of switching the server from a fixed address to a static DHCP lease on a new DHCP server. That's why I need to release/renew it, so it picks up its static lease from the new DHCP server.

Comment: When you set it to DHCP it should auto renew? It certainly shouldn't need to release (what would it even be bound to?).

Comment: Agreed that this, in general, is not something you would want to do... but when setting up the machine to use a static IP in the first place, while remoted in? It just saved my bacon.

Answer (score 34):

Combine the two commands into one

> ipconfig /release && ipconfig /renew

[Microsoft > Docs > PowerShell > Scripting > What's New > What's new in Powershell 7.x > What's new in Powershell 7.0 > Pipeline chain operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7.2#pipeline-chain-operators)

> The && operator executes the right-hand pipeline, if the left-hand pipeline succeeded.

Comment: +1 for answering what they asked instead of touting best practices at them! Although, in my trials here, you might need to stop the RDP session and re-establish (even if it's by name, not IP) as mine seems to just be trying to reconnect to the old IP still. Don't forget to `ipconfig /flushdns` after renewing the IP and giving it time to check in and before trying to find the hostname again!

Comment: Thank you, the most useless answers on any stack site are ones where they ignore the question. Sure, the OP may be in the wrong, but these question show up in search results for those for whom it is correct and useful. I am working remotely on a workstation that has a DHCP reservation, but wanted to test that my newest DHCP DNS settings are functional, and needed to release and renew in one go.

Answer (score 3):

Use AT command. Example
AT 12:58 ipconfig /release

AT 12:59 ipconfig /renew
(this is useful when connecting with psexec, because it does not handle && commands)

Comment: Would definitely work! Use `at` to schedule a renew in a minute or so and schedule the /release for shortly before, or just do the /release yourself

Answer (score 1):

When working remotely, via Remote Desktop, I always combine both commands into one command line entry.

Command Prompt (cmd.exe):

```
ipconfig /release & ipconfig /renew
```

Powershell (powershell.exe, pwsh.exe):

```
ipconfig /release ; ipconfig /renew
```

**IMPORTANT:** If you instead do these command separately, you'll get disconnected without being able to renew!

Answer (score 0):

Since the `at` command is deprecated now and doesn't work in Windows 10 (it gives the error `The AT command has been deprecated. Please use schtasks.exe instead.  The request is not supported.`), here's an example of using `schtasks` to schedule the command to renew later.

```
schtasks /create /tr "ipconfig /renew" /st 02:00 /sc once /tn iprenew
```

Note that this creates a one-time scheduled task which clutters up the scheduled tasks list so simply delete it when you're done via the GUI or the command line.

Answer (score -5):

In powershell it would be ipconfig /release | ipconfig /renew

Comment: This would pipe the output of `ipconfig /release` into `ipconfig /renew`.  I guess both commands would run, but simultaneously - it might try (and fail) renewing before it releases.  `&&` might work instead of `|`, as in Jason's answer.